# Magento 2 - Prices not display with Excluding Tax set in admin

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, tax

I have a issue in Magento 2.2, I want to display all catalog prices without tax, so I set this in the Admin Panel. But the prices in the catalog still contain tax.

What I do wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, I fix this with set Shipping Origin.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that **Tax Class** for products is set to **None**. I think it is set to **Taxable Goods** in admin panel. You can check it by opening product in edit mode.

Comment: No in admin for products is set Taxable Goods

Comment: Then change it to None. And do reindex as well as clear cache. Then try again.

Comment: the same, I think the issue is not in the admin, everything is configured fine there